# react testing library dont work with before each

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library

I have a lot of test cases  and I use a `pre` custom function avoid filling the form at every `test`

when using a function `pre` custom function the test works and passes

```js
  beforeEach(() => {
    render(
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/']}>
        <Signup {...props} />
      </MemoryRouter>
    );
  });

      describe('when form is filled', () => {
        const pre = () => {
          user.type(screen.getByLabelText(labelEmailText), 'email@demo.com')
          user.click(screen.getByText(buttonText))
        }

        test('should render loading', async () => {
          pre()
          await waitFor(() => {
            expect(screen.getByTestId(LOADING_TEST_ID)).toBeInTheDocument()
          })
        })
       // ... a lot of test cases
      })
```

it also should work with `beforeEach` but test doest not work

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    render(
      <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/']}>
        <Signup {...props} />
      </MemoryRouter>
    );
  });

      describe('when form is filled', () => {
        beforeEach(() => {
          user.type(screen.getByLabelText(labelEmailText), 'email@demo.com')
          user.click(screen.getByText(buttonText))
        })
        test('should render loading', async () => {
          await waitFor(() => {
            expect(screen.getByTestId(LOADING_TEST_ID)).toBeInTheDocument()
          })
        })
        // ... a lot of test cases
      })
```

`Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="signup-form-loading-spinner"]`

Why react testing library works with custom function and not with `beforeEach`

Comment: can you please add the snippet of code from where you are calling the 
`render` method of the react testing library

Answer (score 0):

react testing library works with the `beforeEach`, I don't think there is an issue with the `beforeEach` here, I tried with the basic example it works correctly can you log the component using `screen.debug` in the `test` block and see if the component is rendered correctly

```
//App.js
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <label htmlFor="username-input">Username</label>
      <input type="text" id="username-input" data-testid="username" />
      <button>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
}
//App.test.js
beforeEach(() => {
    render(<App />);
})

describe('App component',() => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    user.type(screen.getByLabelText('Username'), 'email@demo.com')
    user.click(screen.getByText('Click'))
  })

  test('renders correctly', async() => {
      // screen.debug()
      //expect(screen.getByTestId('username')).toBeInTheDocument()
      await waitFor(() => {
         expect(screen.getByTestId('username')).toBeInTheDocument()
      })
  });
})
```